# negative numeric number handle in PHP

Tags: php, algorithm

How to change a negative value to a meaningful value.

To make in for clear ---

```
 Input Value- This is -15
 Meaningful value - This is 14
```

How is it possible in PHP.

So when ever a -numeric number is request it get -1 with the request value.

Like --

```
 Iphone -5 Should be Iphone 4
 Ipad -2 Should be iPad 1
```

So first it need to check whether there is any negative number and if there is any negative number alongside with the string than it only reduce one number from it.

```
So if the input is - Iphone -4
it detect there is a - number in the input
than it only take the -4 value from Iphone
```

Anyone know how the solution could be.

Comment: `$meaningfulValue = abs($inputValue) - (($inputValue < 0) ? 1 : 0);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the absolute function [abs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.abs.php)

```
$negNumber = -5;
if( $negNumber < 0 ){
echo abs( $negNumber )  - 1 ;
}
//4
```

---

If you need to replace the value in a sentence, you can use [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
$string = "Iphone -5";
$result = preg_replace_callback('/-\d+/', 'callback', $string);
function callback ($matches) {
return abs($matches[0]) - 1;
}
echo $result;
//Iphone 4
```

---

**DEMO:**

http://ideone.com/C8apl9

Comment: thank you for your answer :), before i did not even know this abs even exists:) , thank you again

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked out. Check my answer, I've added a new option :)

Answer (score 1):

you can do following *as you mentioned in comment*

you need to get that value using [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

```
$str = input value;
preg_match('/-\d+/', $str, $match);
if(count($match) > 0 ):
    (input value * (-1)) -1
endif
```

this will get you your desired value.

```
input value = This is -15
preg_match('/-\d+/', $str, $match);
// here $match[0] contains -15, so
(-15 * (-1)) -1 = 14
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://ideone.com/bPX0GX)

**`/-\d+/`**

`/` is starting and ending delimiter.

`-` this will be required to match `-ve` number. if input is: *`this is 15`*, then this will get nothing from string.

`\d+` matches one or more `digits`.

Hope this will help.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but may be you did not see the question, because in the input value there will be **String** as well, the way you are handling it is not right !

Comment: because i have said **This is -15** , so how you take the input value -15 and process it !!

Comment: @IsakJohnsson How about *you* edit your question to explicitly mention that. (Also showcase prior attempts at extracting the numeric part.)

Answer (score 1):

Take that negative number and add `1` to it and the do an [`abs`](http://php.net/abs). Like `-5+1` which will be `-4`, and then say [`abs(-4)`](http://php.net/abs)) it will give you an absolute value which will be `4`.